# How to say "I am unfortunately getting frustrated"

Tags: grammar

I was trying to say " I am unfortunately getting frustrated." which seemed to suggest some combination of 挫折してしまいました　and ざせつしています but I can't seem to figure out how to put these together.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to go directly from colloquial English into Japanese without explaining the context. What is the frustrating situation? What do you really mean by unfortunately? (For example, taken literally, unfortunately refers to bad luck but is that what you really mean?)

Comment: Tim, it is a really useful comment. I always wonder how a book or study material could summeraize such communication depending on situation.

Comment: Both sentences you quoted use the same expression for "frustration". There's no "putting them together" as they are almost identical.

Comment: The particular thing I was trying to express was the inability to play a song- and how I was unfortunately becoming frustrated. I wanted something more than just saying I was getting frustrated, but I also wanted it to be present tense, and it just didn't work.

Comment: To whom are you expressing this frustration? What is the relationship/level of respect?

Comment: It's not a matter of an alternative way of saying it-I'm more concerned as to why I can't use てしまう　and express continuity with　ています, at the same time.

Comment: @Tony You mean like `〜してしまっています`?

Comment: Yes, does that ever get said?

Comment: @Anthony I edited this question a while ago to try to reflect the question as you explained it in the comments, but that was a mistake--we're not supposed to edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers.  My apologies!  So I tried to fix my mistake by rolling back the edit.  If it turns out that you want to ask the question the way I edited it, please ask it as a separate question :-)  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Go for this one Tony

> 残念ながら私はイラッとしてきました。

Answer (score 1):

So you want to express your (unfortunate) frustration at being unable to play a song?

あーイライラしちゃう！ or something like that would sound natural and gets across that you're not happy about getting frustrated too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this sense of "unfortunately" is like "regrettably" -- you are saying that you feel a certain way but regret feeling like that. You would prefer not to feel frustrated, it's not what you want, but you can't help yourself.

With that in mind I'd suppose something like `不本意ながらイラッとしてきた。`

> **[不本意ながら](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%8D%E6%9C%AC%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89)**
>   自ら望んだわけではないが、不本意ではあるが、といった意味の言い回し。意志とは異なる言動をとったという事を表現する場合に用いられる。

(I wonder if the first half feels too formal for the second half...)

Comment: Excellent comment, the last line.  不本意 is a fairly big word while イラッ is downright colloquial.  Perhaps you could use something like あいにく.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya Thanks, I hope I'll learn to trust my feelings eventually :) Nuance is a tricky thing... >< Incidentally I lost all interest in exploring this answer after the edits to the original question which entirely changed its purpose and wasted 4 answers (it originally asked about a specific sentence, now it asks about how to grammatically combine certain verb forms). Fixes to this answer still won't actually answer the question as it stands so...

Comment: @Hyperworm Oh, my apologies.  That was my edit--I was trying to make the question reflect what the OP was trying to ask based on their comments.  But in retrospect, I probably shouldn't have made that edit after the question already had answers.  (In general, we shouldn't allow questions to be edited in a way that invalidates existing answers.)  To fix my mistake, I reverted the edit!

Answer (score -3):

This should be it
残念な事に俺は今いらいらしている